# Переименовать файлы директории на имена из списка

Tags: python

Необходимо переименовать файлы в директории со списка с названиями.
Вот, что я пытаюсь делать

```py
filename = ['16.txt', '21.txt', '3.txt', '6.txt', '29.txt', '14.txt', '5.txt', '13.txt', '27.txt', '26.txt']
for num, original in enumerate(os.listdir('.\directory')):
    os.rename(original, filename[num])
```

В результате - ошибка:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: '2020-1-16.txt' -> '16.txt'

tree:
C:.
├───directory

Comment: Вы задали правильный вопрос, и получите, надеюсь, правильный ответ. Но не надо так делать. Этот код зависит от порядка файлов в каталоге, что плохо.

Answer (score 1):

**Предупреждение:** код опирается на количество и порядок файлов в каталоге - вещи достаточно произвольные. Не запускайте его, он вам всё испортит. Лучше поставьте задачу которую вам надо решить.

`os.listdir` перечисляет имена файлов, а для переименования нужны пути к файлам.

Символы `\d` в строке показывают что вы не умеете писать строковые литералы:

```
filename = ['16.txt', '21.txt', '3.txt', '6.txt', '29.txt', '14.txt', '5.txt', '13.txt', '27.txt', '26.txt']
d = r'.\directory'
for num, original in enumerate(os.listdir(d)):
    os.rename(os.path.join(d, original), os.path.join(d, filename[num]))
```

Comment: С `\d` вроде нет проблем, питон понимает, что такого спецсимвола нет и воспринимает как обычные отдельные символы. Но так то на всякий лучше конечно использовать `raw string`.

Comment: И я бы лучше через `zip` перебирал оба списка, тут индексы сами по себе не нужны вообще.

Comment: @CrazyElf, не хочу улучшать код построенной на столь ужасной идее - "переименуем файл номер три в каталоге в такое-то имя". :). Работать с файлами можно только по именам.

Comment: Это да, с этим полностью согласен, сама идея опасная )

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя менять то, что вы используете в списке цикла. Сначала добавьте все названия из директории в список `list`.
Далее создайте цикл с `range(len(list))` и там уже вызывайте

```py
os.rename(list[i], f"filename[{i}]")
```

Comment: Да вроде не в этом дело. И не используйте имена переменных, перекрывающие типы питона, например `list`